# Truncate a "real" value in a Text field?

Tags: qt, text, floating-point, qml

I got the follow code :

```
property real compassValue : 3.1415927895412
Text {
    text: "<b>" + compassValue + "°</b>"
}
```

The fact is that I only want to display "3.14". Is there a way to truncate the value ?

Comment: i think if you searched that on google you would have got a faster answer :)

Comment: If I was asking here, that's cause I didn't find something else than "use javascript" on google (which sux btw...)

The solution I found is :
Text {
    text: "<b>" + Math.round(compassValue*100)/100+ "°</b>"
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use the `toFixed()` function:

```
property real compassValue : 3.1415927895412
Text {
    text: "<b>" + compassValue.toFixed(2) + "°</b>"
}
```